# Wordpress POST request fails with XMLHttp and Axios but works with jQuery. What's the difference?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, xmlhttprequest, axios

I'm trying to replace jQuery on all my Wordpress sites.

I have a simple handler `example_handler` that should return "Hello World!"

```
function example_handler() {

  echo 'Hello World!';

  wp_die();

}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_example_handler','example_handler');
add_action('wp_ajax_example_handler','example_handler');
```

When I use **jQuery** I get the expected response:

```
const data = {action: 'example_handler'}

jQuery.post(ajax.url,data,r => {console.log(r);});
```

When I use **Axios** I get a 400 error:

```
axios.post(ajax.url, {
  action: 'bp_contact_form_handler'
})
.then(r => {
  console.log(r);
})
.catch(e => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

When I use **XMLHttp** I get a 400 error:

```
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('POST',ajax.url,true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

request.onload = () => {

  const response = JSON.parse(request.response);

  console.log(request.response);

};

request.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a duplicate as answered here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/282163/wordpress-ajax-with-axios. Using [Qs.js](https://unpkg.com/qs/dist/qs.js) the following code should work with Axios and WordPress. Also typically `ajaxurl` not `ajax.url` is the javascript variable bound to `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`. You might try and point it directly to admin-ajax.php to rule that out as an potential issue.

```
var data = { 
   action: 'bp_contact_form_handler' 
};

axios.post( ajaxurl, Qs.stringify( data ) )
.then(r => {
   console.log(r);
})
.catch(e => {
  console.log(e);
});
```